# FontAwesome - Icons showing as a box - using Compass without rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, compass

My font-awesome icons show as a box, which just means that the icons aren't loading, in my html I just have it as:

```
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>
```

I've checked that font-awesome-sass has installed, properly:
I see in my console that I have:

```
font-awesome-sass (4.3.2.1)
```

Here's my config.rb

```
require "susy"
require 'font-awesome-sass'
css_dir = '_/css'
sass_dir = '_/components/sass'
javascripts_dir = '_/js'
output_style = :compressed
```

styles.scss

```
@import 'compass';
@import 'compass/reset';
@import 'susy';
@import "font-awesome-compass";
@import "font-awesome";


@import 'variables';
@import 'mixins';
@import 'base';
@import 'layout';
@modules 'modules';
```

Is there any step that I missed? Because I am completely unsure of what to do.

error message from browser:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147500037
source: file:///fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff styles.css
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:3): status=2147500037
source: file:///fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf styles.css
downloadable font: no supported format found (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:5)
source: (end of source list)
```

Comment: I would check the network tab of the chrome/firefox developer tools, and see if the browser ever makes an HTTP request for the font. If not, then you know it's an issue with your scss.

Comment: There was an error, I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved a similar issue I was having and want to share the solution. Without seeing your directory structure it is hard to be sure exactly if this will fix your problem.

My hunch is that your issue, like mine, was that the scss variable `$fa-font-path` found in `font-awsome/scss/_variables.scss` is not correctly  referencing the path to your font directory. This is set by default to `../../fonts`, which in my case was incorrect. It is important to note that this path is relative to your compiled css directory.

My directory structure looks something like this:

```
-cdn
  L-css
  L-fonts
    L-font-awesome.woff
    L-font-awesome.woff2
    L-font-awesome.ttf
    L-*other font-awesome files
  L- scripts
-node_modules
  L-font-awesome
-_scss
  L-screen.scss
```

In `screen.scss` I import font awesome: `@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";`(using full path to illustrate location. This should be able to be left to `@import "font-awesome"` since it is a node module).

Then I set the variable in `screen.scss` immediately after that to override the default set in the `node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss` with `$fa-font-path: "../fonts" !default;` , . This prevents the variable from getting reset on further `npm install`'s.

Hope this can help others with similar issues!